# How do I create a server-side template in Dart where I can set a different <title/> for each page?

Tags: dart

First of all, I really like Dart and keep trying to use it in real projects, but then I hit problems like this one where every other web framework has an obvious solution but I can't figure out how to make it work in Dart.

The problem is I would like to render multiple pages using a single base template where I can set the title of the page on the server and then serve the page to the browser.

Something simple like this:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>{{ custom_title }}</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  {{ page_content }}
  <footer>Hey, Seth Ladd!</footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Where I would then pass the template variables which would replace `{{ custom_title }}` and `{{ page_content }}` before being sent back to the browser. Does such a templating solution exist anywhere in the core dart libraries?

I've looked at the [Web Components / Web UI](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/) stuff, but it appears that it's not possible to have components which live outside of the `<body>` tag. I could also alter this easily on the client side, but it's a little dirtier of a solution and raises some SEO concerns (since title is such an important indicator of page content).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try out [mustache](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mustache), a Dart implementation of [mustache templates](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html), a widely used templating syntax, with implementations in a number of languages.

Here's an example:

```dart
import 'package:mustache/mustache.dart';

main() {
    var source = '{{#names}}<div>{{lastname}}, {{firstname}}</div>{{/names}}';
    var template = new Template(source);
    var output = template.renderString({'names': [
        {'firstname': 'Greg', 'lastname': 'Lowe'},
        {'firstname': 'Bob', 'lastname': 'Johnson'}
    ]});
    print(output);
}
```

The Dart team is currently focused on client side development, so many basic server-side features are missing in the core libraries. However take a look at [pub](http://pub.dartlang.org/), there are a number of community maintained packages available.

Also see this similar package: [mustache4dart](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mustache4dart).

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://pub.dev/packages/edart.
Embedded Dart template engine and compiler. Compiles templates to Dart source code.

Example:

`products_index.html`

```html
<%@ import uri="layout.html.g.dart" %>
<%@ import uri="../models/product.dart" %>
<%@ class extends="View" %>
<%@ render params="List<Product> products, HttpRequest request" %>
<p>
    Our cool products list
</p>
<ul class="w3-ul">
    <% for (final product in products) { %>
    <li><%= product.name %>&nbsp;<%= product.price %></li><%
    } %>
</ul>
<%
final layout = layout_html();
layout.title = 'Products';
layout.addTag(HtmlTag('meta', {'description': 'MegaSuperShop cool price list'}));
layout.addBreadcrumb('Products', request.requestedUri.toString());
layout.render(out, request);
%>
```

This template will be compiled into the following source code:

`products_index.html.g.dart`

```dart
// ignore: unused_import
import 'dart:convert';
import 'layout.html.g.dart';
import '../models/product.dart';

class products_index_html extends View {
  String render(List<Product> products, HttpRequest request) {
    final out = StringBuffer();
    out.write('<p>\n');
    out.write('    Our cool products list\n');
    out.write('</p>\n');
    out.write('<ul class="w3-ul">\n');
    for (final product in products) {
      out.write('    <li>');
      out.write(htmlEscape.convert('${product.name}'));
      out.write('&nbsp;');
      out.write(htmlEscape.convert('${product.price}'));
      out.write('</li>');
    }
    out.write('</ul>\n');
    final layout = layout_html();
    layout.title = 'Products';
    layout.addTag(
        HtmlTag('meta', {'description': 'MegaSuperShop cool price list'}));
    layout.addBreadcrumb('Products', request.requestedUri.toString());
    layout.render(out, request);
    return out.toString();
  }
}
```

The layout template is also simple enough to understand.

`layout.html`

```html
<%@ import uri="../html/layout.dart" %>
<%@ import uri="breadcrumbs.html.g.dart" %>
<%@ import uri="footer.html.g.dart" %>
<%@ import uri="header.html.g.dart" %>
<%@ import uri="nav.html.g.dart" %>
<%@ export uri="../html/breadcrumb.dart" %>
<%@ export uri="../html/html_utils.dart" %>
<%@ export uri="../html/view.dart" %>
<%@ class extends="Layout" %>
<%@ render params="StringBuffer body, HttpRequest request, {int statusCode = 400}" %>
<html>

<head>
  <title><%= title %></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <% for (final tag in tags) { %>
  <%== tag %>
  <% } %>
</head>

<body>
  <%== header_html().render(title) %>

  <%== nav_html().render(request) %>

  <div class="w3-container">
    <%== breadcrumbs_html().render(breadcrumbs) %>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-container">
    <%== body %>
  </div>

  <%== footer_html().render() %>

</body>

</html>
<%
body.clear();
body.write(out);
final response = request.response;
response.headers.add('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
response.statusCode = statusCode;
response.write(out);
%>
```

And finally, the source code for class `Layout`.
It can be anything, or it may not be at all (which is not very convenient).

```dart
import 'breadcrumb.dart';
import 'html_utils.dart';

export 'dart:io';

export '../site/site_links.dart';
export 'html_utils.dart';

class Layout {
  final breadcrumbs = <Breadcrumb>[];

  final tags = <HtmlTag>[];

  String title = '';

  void addBreadcrumb(String text, String url) {
    final item = Breadcrumb(text: text, url: url);
    breadcrumbs.add(item);
  }

  HtmlTag addTag(HtmlTag tag) {
    tags.add(tag);
    return tag;
  }
}
```